# Ionic DatePicker local Dateformat?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i have a DatePicker on my Ionic Project and it works fine, unfortunately the Date have the wrong time format. My function:

```
showDatePicker(){
  this.datePicker.show({
    date: new Date(),
    mode: 'date',
    allowOldDates: false,
    androidTheme: this.datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_DARK
  }).then(
    date => this.selectedDate = date
  );
  this.changeAPI();
}
```

My string:

```
this.selectedDate
```

look like this:

> Tue Jan 15 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 Central European Standard Time

But i want that it looks like

> 15.01.2019

How i do this? I try this:

```
this.selectedDate.toLocaleDateString('de-DE');
```

But its doesn´t work. (I use it in the TypeScript file and not in the HTML file)

And how I make, that the date before today in the DatePicker become hidden

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this in the template use the date pipe

```
{{selectedDate | date: 'dd.mm.yyyy'}}
```

If it is inside the component then use the `DatePipe`

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

let date = this.datePipe.transform(this.selectedDate, 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

Comment: I use it in the TypeScript File

Comment: Where i have to write? 

let date = this.datePipe.transform(this.selectedDate, 'dd.mm.yyyy');

In my changeAPI function?